# Script para condicionar de comparación entre valores

Tags: script

Me gustaria saber por qué no funciona el siguiente script de google drive.
Cada vez que se ejecuta, no importa el valor del resultado que compara, le coloca aprobado,,, no me resulta el Suspenso ni el reprobado

si el resultado es 3, le deberia reprobar,..pero le coloca aprobado, ..igualment si esta entre 5 a 6,49 un valor no le coloca el suspenso

esta es la parte del script que hace la comparación:
var promedio  ,...es el rango en el que esta el resultado a comparar

```
 if(promedio >= 6,5){
    form.getRange('E18').setValue("Aprobado")
    }
    else if(promedio >=5; < 6,5) {
    form.getRange('E18').setValue("Suspenso")
    }
    else if(promedio <= 4,49){
    form.getRange('E18').setValue("Reprobado")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque desconozco el lenguaje script de google, veo tres posibles causas del fallo comunes a todos los lenguajes que conozco:

a) Para los decimales usas coma (,) en vez de (.), de ahí que siempre dé por buena la primera condición y devuelva constantemente un aprobado

b) En el segundo if, separas operaciones lógicas con un punto y coma (;), cuando entiendo que deberías utilizar una tercera operación lógica de tipo AND o (&&) aunque, igual en ese lenguaje, el and se codifica con un (;)

c) Y, ya por último, en ese mismo if, en la segunda condición, te faltaría volver a escribir la variable promedio antes de signo de menor que (<)

Son errores muy habituales cuando estás empezando, no te desanimes...

```
if(promedio >= 6.5){
      form.getRange('E18').setValue("Aprobado")
    }
    else if(promedio >=5 && promedio < 6.5) {
      form.getRange('E18').setValue("Suspenso")
    }
    else if(promedio <= 4.49){
      form.getRange('E18').setValue("Reprobado")
    }
 }
```

Comment: Efectivamente fue el punto en los numeros en lugar de la coma y los ampers en un ragno numerico lo que resolvio mi problema. Agradezco mucho tu apoyo..es excelente!!

Comment: Lo de la coma y el punto es inherente al idioma que nos une, a mí aún me sigue pasando después de años. Lo del && y la variable lo veo en clase constatemente, yo creo que nos ha pasado a todos...